# Sql select replacement when id is null

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

Not an expert in sql and have this bad boy sql that does return null when no matches are found. Probably not possible this way?

```
select
CASE WHEN ID_Shoe is null 
                THEN '0000000'
         ELSE 
                ID_Shoe 
END                                 
from t_Shoes WHERE ID_SyncRef = '92C54B3E'
```

Comment: It probably depends on the **actual RDBMS** (and it's version) that you're using (SQL is just the query language - each RDBMS implements it slightly differently)

Comment: using SQL Azure . cheers

Comment: The problem is: if no row matches that `ID_SyncRef`, then **nothing** (not `NULL` - just no row at all) is returned - and you cannot apply `ISNULL` or anything else to **nothing** - that just won't work. ...

Comment: ok i see. cheers marc

Answer (score 0):

I guess I could do something like this

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN
    (select ID_Shoe from ID_Shoes WHERE ID_SyncRef ='92C54B3E-891E-43B3-A122-BE377B3A8D6C') is NULL
THEN 
        '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
ELSE 
     (select ID_Shoe from ID_Shoes WHERE ID_SyncRef = '92C54B3E-891E-43B3-A122-BE377B3A8D6C')       
END as ID_Shoe 
FROM t_Shoes
```